# Symfony months in datepicker rendered as number

Tags: date, symfony, twig

In my symfony app I had a date widget that rendered year/Month(full name)/day. I changed some settings in the formbuilder for ordering etc, but now I cant display the months as 3 letter names. How can I render them as Jan/Feb/...

```
 ->add(
          'geboorteDatum', 'date', array(
            'years' => range(date('Y') - 100, date('Y') - 5),
            'empty_value' => array(
              'year' => 'Jaar',
              'month' => 'Maand',
              'day' => 'Dag'
            ),
            'required' => FALSE,
            'format' => 'dMMy',
          )
        )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Date/Time Format Syntax](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime#TOC-Date-Time-Format-Syntax), you should use triple `M` in order to format as short month:

```
'format' => 'dMMMy'
```

Hope this helps...